# Modal Forms - AjaxStart and End - .load and .ajax() calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I am working on an .NET MVC 3 project where I have made all the `form` based views load in a modal dialog using jQuery.

All of my views are loaded using ajax throughout the project.

I have a jQuery function I call for any link click event which fetches the given url (of a form based view like edit, add, etc) and displays it in a modal dialog as follows:

```
function getFormInModal(url_location, modalWidth, modaltitle, tab) {
    var url = url_location;
    var dialogDiv = $('<div style="display: none;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    dialogDiv.load(url, function () {
        //Enable the client side validation
        var $form = $('form', dialogDiv);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
        var buttons = {
            "Submit": function () {
                //Create a validation summary container
                var valSummary = ModalForms.validationSummary();
                valSummary.setup($form);
                if ($form.valid()) {
                    var postUrl = $form.attr('action');
                    var formData = $form.serialize();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: postUrl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        complete: function (data) {
                            dialogDiv.dialog('close');
                            refresh(tab);
                            $.jGrowl("Submitted Successfully.", { life: 2000 });
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                            if (data && data.errors) {
                                valSummary.addErrors(data.errors);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                dialogDiv.dialog('close');
                $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
            }
        };
        //Load up the dialog
        dialogDiv.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            title: modaltitle,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: buttons,
            width: modalWidth,
            close: function () {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is in the `success` function of the `submit` button of the modal.

It does 3 things:
1. Closes the modal form dialog
2. Notifies the user that the `POST` was successful
3. Refreshes the content in a particular `DIV` via a call to another simple function `refresh()`.

```
function refresh(tabname) {
    if (tabname == "dashboard") {
        $("#dashboard-tab").load("/Sales/Home/Reports");
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", 0);
    }
    if (tabname == "leads") {
        $("#leads-tab").load("/Sales/Lead/Index");
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", 1);
    }
    if (tabname == "retail") {
        $("#retail-tab").load("/Sales/Retail/Index");
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", 2);
    }
    if (tabname == "corporate") {
        $("#corporate-tab").load("/Sales/Corporate/Index");
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", 3);
    }
}
```

Now, separately I have hooked up some events on DOM ready which handle my ajax call status as follows:

```
$("#loading").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '450px',
    title: 'Patience is a virtue!',
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false
});

$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#loading").dialog('open');
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});

$("#loading").ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $("#loading").dialog('close');
    $("html,body").css("overflow", "auto");
});

$("#loading").ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $("#loading").dialog('close');
    $.jGrowl(html(thrownError.toString()), { life: 2000 });
});
```

Everything works perfectly - 
- I click on a link 
- I see the `#loading` modal dialog
- It loads and the `#loading` closes and the `dialogDiv` modal opens
- I click submit and the `#loading` opens up on top of the `dialogDiv`
- When it is done both close and i get the jGrowl notification

The final step which is the loading of the content again also happens, however once my POST is done, and the `.load()` call is made to refresh content the `#loading` modal does not show again.

Basically, `.ajaxStart()` is not firing. I do not know why.

First I had written an `success` function for the ajax post made in the submit button's click event. Then I realized that `complete` might be better.

Even now, thou I am calling the refresh() and hence the `.load()` after the completion of the only other live `.ajax()` call, the `.ajaxStart()` is not working.

Can someone please HELP!!

Comment: Your refresh method is firing, correct?  It's just that the ajaxStart isn't being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see would be the current ajax request is still being processed when you call the refresh function, which is causing your ajaxStart method to not fire.  Try editing your `ready()` method to add a beforeSend method to your ajax settings.  I have found ajaxStart to always act weird, which is why usually the beforeSend is a little more reliable (imo).

```
$(document).ready({
   $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function()
      {
         $('#loading').open();
         $('html,body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
      }
   });
   /* Rest of your initialization here */
});
```

Hope this helps and will work for you.

Comment: actually kyle, this doesn't work either. anyway thanks for the answer, it is a weird and very specific problem so i appreciate you taking the time to break it down.